# Convert 1D array into numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple, one dimensional Python array with random numbers. What I want to do is convert it into a numpy Matrix of a specific shape. My current attempt looks like this:

```
randomWeights = []
for i in range(80):
    randomWeights.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
W = np.mat(randomWeights)
W.reshape(8,10)
```

Unfortunately it always creates a matrix of the form:

[[random1, random2, random3, ...]]

So only the first element of one dimension gets used and the reshape command has no effect. Is there a way to convert the 1D array to a matrix so that the first x items will be row 1 of the matrix, the next x items will be row 2 and so on?

Basically this would be the intended shape:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11, ... ,    16],
 [...,               800]]
```

I suppose I can always build a new matrix in the desired form manually by parsing through the input array. But I'd like to know if there is a simpler, more eleganz solution with built-in functions I'm not seeing. If I have to build those matrices manually I'll have a ton of extra work in other areas of the code since all my source data comes in simple 1D arrays but will be computed as matrices.

Comment: Why is there the number 800 in the last element, and not 80?

Comment: Don't forget `import random`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`reshape()` doesn't reshape in place, you need to assign the result:

```
>>> W = W.reshape(8,10)
>>> W.shape
(8,10)
```

Comment: It should be `reshape(10,8)` for the intended 10 x 8 matrix, btw

Answer (score 2):

You can use `W.resize()`, [ndarray.resize()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize)